# jQuery-File-Upload, fail event fires twice when the connection is lost

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, jquery-file-upload

Consider the following code...

```
var i = 0;

_$uploadWidget.on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    i++;

    console.log('Add file to queue with index: ' i);

    data.index = i;
    data.submit();
});

_$uploadWidget.on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) { 
    console.log('File failed with index: ' + data.index);
});
```

Adding 3 files to the upload control via `$control.fileupload('add', {files: 'file[]'})` will trigger the `fileuploadadd()` event 3 times.  If the server returns a `500` then the `fileuploadfail()` event fires 3 times as expected and you'd see..

```
Add file to queue with index: 1
Add file to queue with index: 2
Add file to queue with index: 3
File failed with index: 1
File failed with index: 2
File failed with index: 3
```

However, if the internet connection is lost then the `fileuploadfail()` event is fired twice for each request.

```
Add file to queue with index: 1
Add file to queue with index: 2
Add file to queue with index: 3
File failed with index: 1
File failed with index: 2
File failed with index: 3
File failed with index: 1
File failed with index: 2
File failed with index: 3
```

I'm pretty sure the second failed event is only fired if the connection is lost before the `POST` is fired.

Can anybody confirm if the jQuery-File-Upload control is handling the retry on queued uploads?  If not, what is it? Whatever is responsible, can it be turned off?

Note: I'm using jQuery-File-Upload version 5.40.1 and jQuery 1.11.0